# Bijection between basis of a constraint matrix and vertices of the feasible polytope

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-programming, polytopes, simplex-method

The [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revised_simplex_method) article for the revised simplex method states

> A vertex of the feasible polytope can be identified as a basis for $B$ for the
> matrix $A$, chosen from the columns of $A$

Here, the feasible polytope is $P = \{x : Ax = b, x \geq 0\}$.

Is the statement is about a bijection between vertices of $P$ and bases of (the column-space of) $A$? What is this bijection?